# Recurring invoice generation

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

i have a question regarding softlayer billing. Wondering how many recurring invoices are generated in a given month for a softlayer customer account. I was under the impression that there can be one recurring invoice generated per month for a customer account. But for our account 976633 i see two recurring invoices generated for the month of Feb 2017 - one on Feb 15th and one on Feb 16th. The anniversary day for the account is 15th of every month.

Appreciate your help.

thanks
reddy

Answer (score 0):

The recurring invoices are generated once each month in your aniversay, in this case your aniversary is gonna be each 16th of each month and a new recurring invoice should be generated. also you can see the date of your next recurring invoice in the Softlayer's control portal, you just need to go to Account->Biling->Invoices

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Some times there exists two **RECURRING invoices, you need to look into the items which belongs for each one**.

There exists some cases in which these items got created too late for batch to pick them up, so the batch will still pick up those billing items just the next day. If you need further assistance, got doubts with these items or the RECURRING invoices, submit a ticket please